# Why can't I import "pygtk" with Python 3.2 from PyDev?

Tags: python, application-development, gtk, eclipse

I have installed Eclipse + PyDev + Python 3.2. Now I have two Python interpreters in PyDev: Python 2.7 and Python 3.2. If I try to execute command `import pygtk` with 2.7 interpreter it works fine, but with Python 3.2 it raises `ImportError: No module named pygtk`.

How can I get PyGTK to work with Python 3.2?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

PyGTK has been deprecated in favor of PyGI+GTK. Because of that, a version of PyGTK for Python 3 was never written.

To use PyGI+GTK in Python 3, you need to install the **python3-gobject** package and do

`from gi.repository import Gtk`

For a quick introduction on porting PyGTK code to PyGI+GTK, see here:

https://live.gnome.org/PyGObject/IntrospectionPorting

For a full tutorial, see here:

http://readthedocs.org/docs/python-gtk-3-tutorial/en/latest/index.html

Comment: "a version of PyGTK for Python 3 was never written." - that's not what the pygtk website says - do you mean was never packaged for ubuntu?

Comment: No, I mean it was never written. What exactly did you see in the pygtk website?

Comment: I misread someting about PyGObject - it's confusing that there are announcements about that on the PyGTK website: > PyGobject 2.26.0 has been released. This is the first stable release in the 2.26.x series and introduces initial support for introspection and Python 3. As usual, sources can be fetched from here. Check out the release announcement and full list of changes.

Answer (score 7):

One small addition: **python3-gobject** was renamed **python3-gi** in Precise. You can still install via the old name, but if you don't need to support anything older than Precise, use **python3-gi** in your debian/control.