# pygtk not available on Focal Fossa (20.04)?

Tags: python3, 20.04, python-2.7, pygtk

**tl;dr** *I cannot install `pygtk` on Focal Fossa (Ubuntu 20.04) anymore but need it for my self-written PyGTK-based Python application.*

I wrote a Python2 application some years ago based on GTK using the `pygtk` package.  This worked fine for years now, I could always use the available Python2 installations, even when Python3 was the more modern variant.

With Focal Fossa (Ubuntu 20.04) Python2 support has been dropped, so I thought, no problem, I can upgrade my application to Python3.  After doing it, I tried to install `pygtk` for Python3 using `sudo pip3 install pygtk` but this failed:

```
$ sudo pip3 install pygtk
Collecting pygtk
  Using cached pygtk-2.24.0.tar.bz2 (2.4 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-nezwkvr_/pygtk/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-nezwkvr_/pygtk/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-nezwkvr_/pygtk/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-nezwkvr_/pygtk/
    Complete output (4 lines):
    ********************************************************************
    * Building PyGTK using distutils is only supported on windows. *
    * To build PyGTK in a supported way, read the INSTALL file.    *
    ********************************************************************
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

(The mentioned `pygtk-2.24.0.tar.bz2` file wasn't to be found anymore, so I could not even look at the `INSTALL` file as suggested.)

I also found no package for `apt install ...` that would have installed it.

Alright, I thought, back to Python2.  But unfortunately I cannot install `pygtk` for Python2 as well.  I *can* install a `python2` package, but there is no `pip` command and/or module anymore for Python2.  (So neither `pip ...` nor `pip2 ...` nor `python2 -m pip` work.  Maybe I just didn't find the correct way to do it.)

So I also could not install the Python2 version.

Then I briefly tried looking up how to install a non-packaged version of pygtk but that quickly dove even deeper into more dependencies (`jhinstall`, etc.) which seemed like taking even more time, and I'm lacking the experience in solving all these.

So I guessed maybe there is an easier solution and maybe someone here knows how to easily solve this issue.  If nothing here pops up I will have to invest the time and solve the dependencies the hard way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I import "pygtk" with Python 3.2 from PyDev?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97023/why-cant-i-import-pygtk-with-python-3-2-from-pydev). You likely have the `python3-gi` deb package installed already -- you don't need to install it through pip.

Comment: Indeed this seems to be a solution!  So `pygtk` is discontinued in favor of a different framework API.  Unfortunately this seems to mean I will have to modify larger parts of my code.  It's not as simple as a `sed 's/import gtk/from gi.repository import Gtk as gtk/g'`.

Answer (score 21):

You can install `python-gtk2` manually from 18.04 LTS repository:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

and use it as usual :)

Comment: I will consider using it but I prefer using official packages from official sources.

Comment: I came here looking for a trick for "diffuse" and I see your PPA has it. Maybe I should just use meld, but diffuse is what I'm used to. Thanks!

Comment: nice work. It works also for `Linux Mint 20` which is based on `Ubuntu 20.04`