# "No package 'pygtk-2.0' found" on Ubuntu 20.04 even after installing python-gtk2 from archives

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, python-2.7, pygtk

I am trying to install [blueman](https://github.com/blueman-project/blueman) which seems to have pygtk-2.0 as a dependency.
When doing `./configure`,  it stops here:

```
configure: error: Package requirements (pygtk-2.0 >= 2.12.0) were not met:

No package 'pygtk-2.0' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables PYGTK_CFLAGS and PYGTK_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config. See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

Since python-gtk2 is not available through `apt`,  I installed it manually from a package as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235271/pygtk-not-available-on-focal-fossa-20-04).

Then tried configuring blueman again, but I still get the same error.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Looking at https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/blueman, I see only Py3 packages as dependencies.

Answer (score 5):

The needed *pygtk-2.0.pc* file was last available for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and came from [`python-gtk2-dev` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=pygtk-2.0).

So you have to download and install this development package with dependencies manually by using commands below:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2-dev_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_all.deb

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ./python-gtk2-dev_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_all.deb  ./python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

and then check its registration by `pkg-config --list-all | grep pygtk-2.0`  .

Also please note that modern Gtk3.0 based version of BlueMan [exists](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/blueman) in official *universe* pocket for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. You can install BlueMan as simple as

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get install blueman
```